# Cant create an AVD in AVD Manager

Tags: android, android-emulator

i have downloaded the files for android 4.0.3 in avd manager including all the extras. now when im creating a new avd with the settings given below, as soon as i click the create avd button, the window just becomes not responding for some time(about 10-20 secs) and then it starts responding.....bu nothing happens...again when i click, again same thing happens.
please help me out of this. and just wanted to tell than i am using windows 7 x86 and its installed in the e: drive not in the c: drive and also i don't have eclipse installed, but its not necessary is it?....is that creating the problem?
I put in these details while creaing the new avd:

```
name : avd
target: Android 4.0.3 - API Level 15
CPU/ABI : ARM (armeabi-v7a)
SdCard : Size: 4 GiB
Snapshot : Not Enabled
Skin : Built-in: Default (WVGA800)
```

Comment: The emulator takes awhile to get started. At what does it not respond? Are you reaching the "lock" screen?

Comment: @Yawus no the emulator doesn't get created only!....as i click the create button its just kind of hangs for some time and then nothing happens....its just as it was before i clicked the button.

Answer (score 0):

I tested you avd configuration and I had problems to create the emulator too, It was really slow but finally I could created it. I think maybe you should install eclipse, probably your android sdk is incompleted or it's missing another pluging.

Comment: which one will i download? Eclipse IDE for Java Developers?

Comment: You can use Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers

Comment: "We recommend the "Eclipse Classic" version" mention in developer site http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html